# Pass a value to a partial view from parent view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a Web app where my controller passes a model to the parent view like so:

```
 public ActionResult Results()
 {
     //Processing

     return View ("ParentView",model);
 }
```

Within my "ParentView" I will do render a partial view like so:

```
 @Html.Partial("_PartialView", anotherModel)
```

Now I would like to not touch the `anotherModel` at all.

But what I am trying to do is pass a value to `_PartialView` from the `ParentView`.

I know I can pass something like `ViewBag.Value="Text"` from the Controller to the `"ParentView"`, however is something like that doable from `"ParentView"` to `"_PartialView"`?

Basically I want to add a value in the `model` that is being used by `"ParentView"`, and somehow pass it down to `"_PartialView"`

Comment: With the tags [model][controller] and [core] (which is not related to [.net]), did you mean something like [tag:asp.net-core-mvc]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to create a View model. you can create it by 3 ways

first way

```
public class ViewModel
{
public class ParentViewModel {get; set;}
public class ChildViewModel {get; set;}
}
```

in this case your view

```
@model ViewModel
 
    
...... //html is using @Model.ParentViewModel)

  @Html.Partial("_PartialView", @Model.ChildViewModel)
```

second way

```
public class ParentViewModel:ChildViewModel
```

in this case the same model can be used for both

```
@model ParentViewModel
 
    
...... //html is using @Model)

  @Html.Partial("_PartialView")
```

The third way can be used if it is possible to use interface to another model

partial view

```
@model IAnotherModel
```

viewmodel

```
public class ViewModel:IAnotherModel
```

view is the same as the second way

Comment: Appreciate your answer

Answer (score 1):

You can pass properties from your `PageView` Model to your `PartialView` like this:

```
@Html.Partial("_PartialView", @Model.AnotherModel)
```

You then set the Model of your `_PartialView` to be of the type of `AnotherModel`.